# Enable only if is different than 0 or null in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

### The Goal

Enable the button just if the input is different than zero (0), zero zero (00) or null/empty.

### The Problem

I do not know the syntax.

### The Code

**HTML:**

```
<input class="quantity float-left" name="productQuantity" maxlength="2"
       type="text" 
       data-bind="value: ProductLayout.itemQuantity, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" 
/>
<span class="float-left">/@(Model["MeasureName"])(s)</span>
<button class="btn btn-add btn-mini float-right" 
        data-bind="enable: ProductLayout.itemQuantityValid">Adicionar</button>
```

**JS:** In the following code I illustrate what I want to do. What happens? The button doesn't enable if `&& null` exist.

```
function ProductLayoutViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.itemQuantity = ko.observable("");
    self.itemQuantityValid = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.itemQuantity() != "0" && null;
    }, this);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uW2ud/)

View :

```
<input class="quantity float-left" name="productQuantity" maxlength="2" type="text" 
       data-bind="value: itemQuantity, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />

<span class="float-left">/@(Model["MeasureName"])(s)</span>

<button class="btn btn-add btn-mini float-right"
        data-bind="enable: itemQuantityValid">Adicionar</button>
```

ViewModel :

```
function ProductLayoutViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.itemQuantity = ko.observable("");
    self.itemQuantityValid = ko.computed(function () {
        var q = self.itemQuantity();
        return q != "0" && q != '00' && q != null && q != '';
    }, this);
};

var vm = new ProductLayoutViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

**[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uW2ud/)**

Comment: It works! But you know, I thought I had a better way of doing instead of using `&&`. By the way, thanks! +1

Comment: Yes you could use ko.validation : https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation

Comment: I think it is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to write

```
return self.itemQuantity() != "0" && self.itemQuantity() != null;
```

Comment: Yes — you are right. But this is not enough yet. `null` is wrong, I changed to `""` and I need to check if is different than `00`. Thanks anyway!